# Why does pushNewScope/popScope not work for Getit?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
    var db1 = getIt<ProductDatabase>();
    getIt.pushNewScope();

    getIt.registerSingleton(ProductDatabase());

    var db2 = getIt<ProductDatabase>();
    getIt.popScope();
```

I'm trying to understand how pushNewScope works in Getit. But after pushing new
scope, it is complaining about the instance already being registered for 'ProductDatabase'.

How to use pushNewScope & popScope the right way so there are two instances of the same object and when I pop the scope, the previous most instance comes alive and rest if popped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One must await the `getIt.popScope()` call for it to work.